# MYSQL timestamp column auto update even if there is no changes?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a column update_date in a table and type is timestamp. I set the deault value by using phpmyadmin drop down menu to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. But later when ever I run sql UPDATE x SET ...
 it updates the timestamp column if only there is a changes in any of the columns. What I would like to achieve is that whether there is a change or not set the current time everytime the update sql runs. Is there any way of doing it in the mysql or I need to set the update_date explicitly every time the update is called?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly update the column. From the MySQL manual, [TIMESTAMP properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> The auto-update TIMESTAMP column, if there is one, is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. **If all other columns are set to their current values, the TIMESTAMP column does not change.** Automatic updating does not apply if the TIMESTAMP column is explicitly assigned a value other than NULL.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I have only one timestamp column in the row. So you sayin g I should change the default value to null and then update it explicitly every time the sql is run or I can leave the default type as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: The other thing is that when I run this code nothing is updated "UPDATE x SET update_date = NOW() " from mysql_query ? what would be the reason?

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this ? [To update the timestamp even if there was no update in actual values]