# Is it possible to merge two tables by primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, which I need to merge, and they are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `legacy_bookmarks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` text,
  `title` text,
  `snippet` text,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`snippet`)
)
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `legacy_links` (
  `id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookmark_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('public','private') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'public',
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `bookmark_id` (`bookmark_id`)
)
```

As you can see, "legacy_links" contains the ID for "legacy_bookmarks". Am I able to merge the two, based on this relationship?

I can easily change the name of the ID column in "legacy_bookmarks" to "bookmark_id", if that makes things any easier.

Just so you know, the order of the columns, and their types, must be exact, because the data from this combined table is then to be imported into the new "bookmarks" table.

Also, I'd need to able to include additional columns (a "modification" column, populated with the "datetime" values), and change the order of the ones I have.

Any takers?

Comment: You want to combine these into one table?

Comment: Sure You can make a relationship here but normally `bookmark_id` should be foreign key to `legacy_bookmarks`. But even without it You can merge them - SELECT b.* FROM `legacy_bookmarks` b JOIN `legacy_links` l ON l.bookmark_id = b.id;

Comment: For "modification" column see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716397/mysql-timestamp-column-auto-update-even-if-there-is-no-changes)

Comment: Yes, and the order of the columns, and their types, must be exact, because the data from this table is then to be imported into the new "bookmarks" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Up to you to change the order of the columns]

```
CREATE TABLE `legacy_linkss` AS
SELECT l.id, l.url, l.title, l.snippet, l.datetime AS modification, b.user_id, b.status
FROM
    `legacy_links` l 
    JOIN `legacy_bookmarks` b ON b.id = l.bookmark_id
;
```

Afterwards, after checking the consistency and adding manually the constraints, you may:

```
DROP TABLE `legacy_links`;
DROP TABLE `legacy_bookmarks`;
RENAME TABLE `legacy_linkss` TO `legacy_links`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a join, and you would do it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM legacy_bookmarks lb
INNER JOIN legacy_links ll ON ll.bookmark_id = lb.id
```

Comment: Joins I'm familiar with. But done between two tables is something new. Eric, I'll have play.

Comment: @WayneSmallman: it's rare that you need to join a table only to itself, so I'm wondering how you've managed to be doing only self-joins all these years, with no idea that joins existed to connect different tables...

Comment: Yes, I realise that sounds weird. No, I do use joins, but it looks as though I've thought this is more complex than it is is, which it appears not to be!